# Android - Jsoup connect succeeds on emulator but fails on device

Tags: java, android, cookies, connection, jsoup

When trying to login using Jsoup connect on a website (in order to retrieve cookies for future requests), the request works fine on the emulator but not on my device.
Here is a piece of code :

```
// login data passed as a body using application/xxx-form-urlencoded
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(login_url)
                .data(list)
                .headers(headers)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .ignoreHttpErrors(true);
Connection.Response res = conn.execute();
```

Everything is fine on the emulator : it returns a 200 with the cookies I am expecting. On device it returns a 404 : according to some tests on Postman it means that the login fails, but I can't figure out why... Both connection parameters are identical.

The SDK version is ok, I tried with other methods (HttpUrlConnection) but it won't work either..

Is there something I am missing ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: what's the `logcat` error?

Comment: there are no errors on logcat, it just fails to login

Answer (score 0):

I did a HttpUrlConnection instead and it solves my problem.